# what permissions do i have?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is their a Global Variable for batch files witch shows if i have admin permissions or not ie %ADMIM% if not is their a command line exe that will tell me?

I am writing a batch file and i want it to do one thing if i have admin and another if its a regular user.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There can be more than "admin and regular user". It would better to check if you have permissions to do what you are going to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this trick:

```
@echo off
(>nul 2>&1 "cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system")&&(
    echo.I am admin
)
```